# How to open external link with using UITextView?

Tags: swift, hyperlink, uitextview

I am displaying an HTML file in UITextView using attributedString.

Everything works fine, but when I want to click on the link in the text, I get an error like this:

> The operation couldn't be completed. (OSStatus error -10814.)

The methods I use are as follows. Can you help?

```
    func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWith URL: URL, in characterRange: NSRange, interaction: UITextItemInteraction) -> Bool {
    
    if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(URL) {
        
         UIApplication.shared.open(URL)
        
     } else {
         
         print("Can't open url on this device")
         
     }
    return false
 }
```

And this is my info.Plist:

```
    <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
<string>applewebdata</string>
</array>
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to display the HTML file in a WKWebView?

Comment: Yes I also tried using WKWbView but various problems occurred. I also turned to this method.

Comment: Is the file included in your Xcode project, or is it an external webpage?  Assuming it's an included file in your project, you can get the url with this syntax:  `let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "YOUR_FILE_NAME", withExtension: "html")`.  In my test project, I have a button set the source of a WKWebView to the included HTML file with the line `webView.load(URLRequest(url: url!))`.  It is working for me on the simulator with no errors.  Maybe instead of what you're doing now with the AttributedString, you could just detect clicks within that range of characters, and then (continued)

Comment: use a function to load the HTML page, instead of that textView method?

Comment: Let me summarize it for you. I have a local HTML page opened with WKWebview that I created for users to write. I keep this page in xCode.

Users write their articles and send them to the server, there is no problem here.

Then I open a textview to read the posts they wrote. And I'm using a method that converts the html structure to an attributedstring. Everything works fine but when I click on the link I get an error like this.

Comment: Yes I can use WKWebView but I just  don't want it.

Comment: What do you get if you print `URL.scheme`? The scheme you get, such as http, https, mailto, someCustomAppScheme, etc., is what should be added to the `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` list.

Comment: Also, how far in the `shouldInteractWith` method do you get? Does `canOpenURL` succeed? What is the return value from calling `open(URL)`?

Comment: Hi @HangarRash, URL.scheme is 'applewebdata' and canOpenURL not succeed return this: canOpenURL: failed for URL: "applewebdata://994B80FD-CD54-4FDE-B630-1EF92A47436E/www.google.com". BTW just 'https' links opening, other links failed